# loading document with error when open with pdf js

Tags: php, mysql, pdf.js

I have a strange question regarding PDF.JS and PHP
Using PDF.JS, to open pdf you should use on browser:

```
http:// ...url... /viewer.html?file=[filename]
```

I have changed viewer.html extension to viewer.php and developed an additional file document.php to get data from database and load a local PDF file, and I use in this way to get PDF

```
... viewer.php?file=document.php&control=5E71581C52B96
```

**All work great** , AS ESPECTED, but i'm experiencing trouble when get variables from database.

When I Use fileurl like this, PDF load correctly:

```
$fileurl = 'D:\Drive\_DEV\storage\220\2020-03-17\00000000002\1584486427900.pdf';
```

When I use fileurl like this (variables from database) PDF not open and have error
Corrupted or inválid PDF Invalid PDF structure

```
$fileurl = $storage_path.'\\'.$storage_folder.'\\'.$document;
```

If I echo, $fileurl in both cases i have exactly same result.

Regarding SQL QUERY below, on WHERE Clause if I change '$doc_control' (from request) with '5E71581C52B96' (instead '$doc_control') PDF load correctly into pdf.js

If I echo $doc_control, number is exactly same, only difference is how put value on WHERE (number or variable)

If i open document.php work with no problems.

What do I Wrong? Any help is very appreciated.

```
DOCUMENT.PHP

// REQUEST
$doc_control = $_REQUEST['control'];

// Read database
SELECT *
FROM docs
WHERE doc_control = '$doc_control'



// FILE PATH

   $fileurl = $storage_path.'\\'.$storage_folder.'\\'.$document;    


// READ PDF          
header("Content-type:application/pdf");
header("Content-Disposition:inline;filename=".$fileurl);
//@readfile($fileurl);

$file=fopen($fileurl, "r") or die('Unable to open file');
echo fread($file,filesize($fileurl));
fclose($file);
```